# Detecting button press over computer network

Tags: ethernet, io, network

I would like to make a networked device (along the lines of hotel room service call) that has multiple input lines that may be uniquely identified on a computer on the network.

I found a [product](http://microcontrollershop.com/product_info.php?cPath=346_349&products_id=3771&osCsid=147001be4b8bebbc44c53f09a6d3bf17) with similar functionality.

I assume the device will require a microcontroller interfaced with an Ethernet I/O controller? Do I need to have an OS to generate TCP/IP message packets that may be detected on a PC? Kindly suggest a block scheme I can follow to do this.

Comment: take a look at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : Agreed, I request for a scheme, I can start working with, would appreciate if i get a road-map and i can explore the specifics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me what it's exactly what you want. I think it's like the following: you have a number of lines which will have to be interfaced by a microcontroller, and this microcontroller sends a signal to a computer. The computer processes this signal.

For the microcontroller part, you can use a chip with integrated ethernet like the [PIC18F67J60](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en026445) Olin mentioned. You can also use a smaller (easier to program) chip with an external ethernet chip like the [ENC28J60](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en022889). You can write software for the microcontroller using [Microchip's TCP/IP stack](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537041), [Olin Lathrop's TCP/IP stack](http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm) (see under "Networking Example Firmware") or the implementation by Matthew Schinkel in [Jalv2](http://justanotherlanguage.org/).

Since the microcontroller sends a signal to the computer, it's the easiest to make the computer the server and the microcontroller the client. That would mean you need some sort of server on the computer. I'd recommend you to go for an HTTP server, because there's the most information available for it. For linux, you can use a [LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/) server - for Windows, use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or XAMPP.

You'll have to make some server-side script that processes the request from the client. The client has to call that script. You could, for example, make the client request `/button.php?button=17` when button number 17 has been pressed. Then, the server-side script could be like this:

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['button'])) {                    // Check if ?button exists
    die('The button variable is mandatory.');     // If not, quit
}

$button = (int) $_GET['button'];                  // Cast ?button to an integer
if ($button == 0) {                               // Check if it was an integer
    die('Invalid button number.');                // If not, quit
}

// Do stuff with $button
```

Here's a block scheme:

[image]

Let me explain this.

- The **Buttons & other IO** form the input for the microcontroller you're going to use. This would be the buttons you're going to interface, but could also be other things, like I2C / SPI devices, or whatever.
- You can get information from this IO with basic **chip programming**. The chip has to read values from the inputs.
- The **chip** (could be a PIC) with **ethernet** (could be built-in) processes the input information, and transmits it to the IP of the **server**, say, 192.168.0.10.
- For this, it has to be sent to the **router** on IP 192.168.0.1 first using the **TCP/IP stack**. You won't notice this on the chip. It's just like you contact the **server** directly.
- The **router** processes the packet and sends it to the **server** on 192.168.0.10. You don't have to make this, the **router** does it by itself.
- The **server** gets an HTTP request and needs to process it. It sends a response back to the router on 192.168.0.10, which forwards it to the chip. This isn't shown in the block scheme because it isn't needed in this application: data has to be sent from the **chip** to the **server**, but not back.
- The data from the **chip** can be used by the **server** to show it on a screen, store it in a file, or do something else with it. That's entirely up to you.

You can also, as Olin suggests in the comments, use a TCP server instead of an HTTP server. This is possible and more efficient (which is a theoretical pro, you won't notice it). I'd recommend a starter in networking to go with an HTTP server. There are loads of information on the topic and it's very easy to get started with. If you know stuff about networking already, you can build a TCP server as well. Neither of the two servers would be more complex to implement on the client-side.

Comment: 1: I don't see how a "smaller" chip than the 18F67J60 would be easier to program. Size is orthagonal to difficulty. The advantage of the '67J60 is that it has MAC/PHY built in. 2: I also have a free network stack for the 'J60 line, included in the PIC Development Tools release at http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm. 3: Why the complexity of HTTP when you can create a simple TCP server just to accept data from these devices?

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. So if I read you correctly, The scheme would be to read the pins to be monitored, encode them into HTTP request, and send over TCP/IP (using the library source you mentioned). On the PC side decode the message and use it in some application. Any network specifics I need to take care of ?

Comment: @OlinLathrop 1: the 18F67J60 has a datasheet of nearly 500 pages. For example the 16F88 has less than half of it; so it might be easier for starters (me included). 2: thanks, I'll edit that in. 3: there's much more information available on HTTP servers. Since there are open source solutions for HTTP, it won't make the code much more complex.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : What level protocol do i really need to go upto given that my intention is just to detect line's status ( Hi / Lo ) in my desktop application ?

Comment: @Bleamer exactly. You won't need network specifics, although it would be useful to have a static IP address or hostname of the server so you can hardcode it in the chip. Also, the encoding of the HTTP request won't be that hard, it's a base string with the addition of the button number.

Comment: @CamilStaps : Thank you. This would be the most minimalist  scheme ? Pardon my understanding of networking.

Comment: @Bleamer not the minimalist, but the easiest in my opinion. I added a block scheme with explanation for you.

Comment: @Bleamer no problem :) good luck!

Comment: The PIC 16F88 is way too small to support a TCP network stack.  A large part of the '67J60 manual describes the details of the MAC/PHY.  Either you use existing software to drive it, or you have to read the equivalent datasheet for the external MAC/PHY.  The '67J60 datasheet looks big because it's all in one document.

Comment: @OlinLathrop : You suggest going with 18F67J60 ?

Comment: @OlinLathrop true, it's a bad example. But I'm sure there are chips that are easier to start with than the 18F67J60 that do have enough program memory for a TCP/IP stack. On the other hand, I've never tried the 18F67J60, and it might be quite easy to get started with it.

Comment: @Bleamer: I was thinking of writing your own TCP server on the host computer end.  That is a easy thing to do.  Yes, I think a 18F67J60 is a good chip for this, or its larger brother the 18F87J60 if you have a lot of buttons to connect.  It is the 80 pin version of the 64-pin '67J60.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a low-cost microcontroller I use called an "Electric Imp", its small (the size of a SD card) and contains all you need to have a button that makes secure connection via wifi to the internet and even work on battery power.

Of course once your button press is out the internet you have 1001 different options with what you can do with that.

One really nice feature is your code-updates are pushed down to the device from the internet so it is field upgradable.

Answer (score 1):

Get a micro with Ethernet capability, like the PIC18F67J60, and wire all the buttons to it. The micro debounces the buttons.  When it sees activity worth reporting, it opens a TCP connection to a known server at a known port, sends the info, and closes the connection.